# RollupJS .write promise

Tags: promise, rollup, rollupjs

I am using rollup in a NodeJS process. It works but I'm wondering about an output

```
async function build(foo) {
    try {
        const bundle = await rollup.rollup(rollupConfig.inputOptions);
        const whatever = await bundle.write(rollupConfig.outputOptions);
        return whatever
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.error('error:', err)
    }
}
```

The files are written correctly, but `whatever` is undefined. Should it be *something*?

If there is an error then the catch works ok

Comment: No, what something would you expect `write` to have as a result?

Comment: Maybe it could return something in order to validate? Just a thought, I won't die on this hill.

Comment: Validate what? I'd expect it to throw an exception if there's an error during write.